# Manage the update order for queries in JPA

Tags: spring, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am creating a simple kanban application as following, each kanban is made out of a sequence of stages and each stage have a level field to define its position. I want to be able to add, move and remove stages at will so I have to keep the level of each stage consistent, simple enough.

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "kanbans")
data class Kanban (
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        var id: Int? = null,

        @get:NotNull
        @get:NotBlank
        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
        var name: String? = null,

        @get:NotNull
        @get:NotBlank
        @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
        var description: String? = null,

        @get:NotNull
        @Column(name = "closed", nullable = false)
        var closed: Boolean? = null,

        @get:NotNull
        @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
        var createdAt: LocalDateTime? = null,

        @get:NotNull
        @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
        var updatedAt: LocalDateTime? = null,
)
```

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "stages")
data class Stage (
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        var id: Int? = null,

        @get:NotNull
        @get:NotBlank
        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
        var name: String? = null,

        @get:NotNull
        @get:NotBlank
        @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
        var description: String? = null,

        @get:NotNull
        @Column(name = "closed", nullable = false)
        var closed: Boolean? = null,

        @get:NotNull
        @Column(name = "level", nullable = false)
        var level: Int? = null,

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "stage")
        var tasks: List<Task> = ArrayList(),

        @get:NotNull
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "kanban_id", nullable = false)
        var kanban: Kanban? = null,

        @get:NotNull
        @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
        var createdAt: LocalDateTime? = null,

        @get:NotNull
        @Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = false)
        var updatedAt: LocalDateTime? = null,
)
```

When creating the first stage its always assigning its level at 0 and then when adding new ones the level will define the stage position at the list of stages. The problem is that when I try to update the previous existing stages to give place to the new one, the only way I found to make this work is to place a `saveAndFlush` call in a loop but I find it to be not a good ideia.

```kotlin
@Repository
interface StageRepository : JpaRepository<Stage, Int> {
    fun findAllByKanbanAndLevelGreaterThanEqualOrderByLevelDesc(kanban: Kanban, level: Int): List<Stage>

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE Stage s SET s.level = s.level + 1 WHERE s.kanban = :kanban AND s.level >= :level")
    fun incrementLevelForKanbanStagesWhereLevelIsGreaterThan(kanban: Kanban, level: Int)
}
```

the `incrementLevelForKanbanStagesWhereLevelIsGreaterThan` method fails as the database have a unique constraint to `level` and `kanban_id` with the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "stages_kanban_id_level_key"
  Detalhe: Key (kanban_id, level)=(337, 1) already exists.
```

this is obviously happening because it is trying to update level 0 to level 1 before updating level 1 to level 2 and so I have tried:

```kotlin
@Transactional
    @Query("UPDATE Stage s SET s.level = s.level + 1 WHERE s.kanban = :kanban AND s.level >= :level ORDER BY s.level DESC")
    fun incrementLevelForKanbanStagesWhereLevelIsGreaterThan(kanban: Kanban, level: Int)
```

which does not compile,

```kotlin
@Service
@Transactional
class StageCrudService: CrudService<Stage, Int, StageRepository, StageValidationService>() {
    @Throws(ValidationException::class)
    override fun create(model: Stage): Stage {
        prepareToCreate(model)
        validationService.canSave(model)
        incrementKanbanStageLevels(model)
        return repository.save(model)
    }

    private fun prepareToCreate(model: Stage) {
        val now = LocalDateTime.now()
        val closed = model.closed ?: false
        model.closed = closed
        model.createdAt = now
        model.updatedAt = now
        model.level = model.level ?: 0
    }

    private fun incrementKanbanStageLevels(model: Stage) {
        val level = model.level ?: 0
        val stages = repository.findAllByKanbanAndLevelGreaterThanEqualOrderByLevelDesc(model.kanban!!, level)
        stages.forEach { stage ->
            stage.level = stage.level?.plus(1)
        }
        repository.saveAll(stages)
        repository.flush()
    }
}
```

and

```kotlin
private fun incrementKanbanStageLevels(model: Stage) {
        val level = model.level ?: 0
        val stages = repository.findAllByKanbanAndLevelGreaterThanEqualOrderByLevelDesc(model.kanban!!, level)
        stages.forEach { stage ->
            stage.level = stage.level?.plus(1)
            repository.save(stage)
        }
        repository.flush()
    }
```

but both fails the same way as the query. Now the question is:

Is there a better way to manage the update order for this kind of situation instead of doing:

```kotlin
private fun incrementKanbanStageLevels(model: Stage) {
        val level = model.level ?: 0
        val stages = repository.findAllByKanbanAndLevelGreaterThanEqualOrderByLevelDesc(model.kanban!!, level)
        stages.forEach { stage ->
            stage.level = stage.level?.plus(1)
            repository.saveAndFlush(stage)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are possibly trying to implement something that can be managed for you via the JPA `@OrderColumn` annotation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

> Specifies a column that is used to maintain the persistent order of a
> list. The persistence provider is responsible for maintaining the
> order upon retrieval and in the database. The persistence provider is
> responsible for updating the ordering upon flushing to the database to
> reflect any insertion, deletion, or reordering affecting the list.

To use this you would need to make the relationship bi-directional and the level should be maintained by your JPA provider as items are added to and removed from the list

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kanbans")
data class Kanban (
        .....

        @get:NotNull
        @get:NotBlank
        @OrderColumn(name = "level")
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "kanban")
        var stage: List<Stage> = ArrayList()

       .....
}
```

So you can then remove and add items (at any position) and the sequence will be maintained for you.

Comment: "The OrderColumn annotation is specified on a OneToMany or ManyToMany relationship or on an element collection", this field is not an element collection the @OrderColumn doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Yes, sorry. You need to make the relationship bi-directional and put it on the one to many.